# How to get a cell value from NSTableView in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have probably a dumb question, but Im pretty new to Cocoa, so I don't feel bad asking it :)

I have a tableview filled with some numeric values. What I need is that when the user clicks on a particular cell some action happens involving this cell value.

For example: table has values from 1 to 10, user clicks on a value and the square of this value appears somewhere on the window. (user clicks on 3 and 9 appears somewhere next to the table)

I will really appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all set your app delegate to be the delegate of the table view (use the setDelegate method).Then declare your app delegate to implement the NSTableViewDelegate protocol (probably you've already done this - If not, add NSTableViewDelegate after NSApplicationDelegate).
Then implement this method:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
```

This way you are noticed whenever the selection of the table view changes (use table view's selected row method to know which row has changed).
There are also a lot of method that you can implement in the NSTableViewDelegate, to be noticed when other events occur.

PS: Not dumb question.

Comment: I don't think that I want to change the rows...I simply want to be able to click on the specific cell and use its value or invoke some action involving its value...but thank you anyways for useful info!

Comment: @EugeneGordin, the method tableViewSelectionDidChange: is called whenever you click on a row -- this is what you want to use. It doesn't mean that you're changing anything about the row, just that you made a selection (either a different selection from one you made before or your first selection when the app starts).